# Meteor deploying with Android build Error

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

I'm trying to follow instructions on the Meteor tutorial page located here https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile to get an app running on the Android emulator. I've started a new blank test app, but when I run `meteor run android` I get the following errors:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --emulator:
   Error: Command failed:                     
   /home/cameron/Projects/Meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
   --emulator
   { [Error:
   /home/cameron/Projects/Meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew:
   Command failed with exit code 1] code: 1 } 'Error:
   /home/cameron/Projects/Meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew:
   Command failed with exit code 1\n    at ChildProcess.whenDone
   (/home/cameron/Projects/Meteor/simple-todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)\n
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)\n    at ChildProcess.emit
   (events.js:172:7)\n    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)\n
   at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:330:11)\n    at emitOne
   (events.js:77:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)\n    at
   Pipe._onclose (net.js:487:12)'
   at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:151:23)
   at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
   => awaited here:
   at Function.Promise.await
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
   at CordovaProject.runCommands (/tools/cordova/project.js:715:22)
   at CordovaProject.run$ (/tools/cordova/project.js:261:10)
   at tryCatch
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke]
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:337:22)
   at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
   at tryCatch
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
   at invoke
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:139:20)
   at
   /home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:184:11
   at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:183:16)
   at AsyncIterator.enqueue
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:206:13)
   at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
   at Object.runtime.async
   (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:226:14)
   at
   /home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:32:39

/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^
undefined
 => awaited here:
    at Function.Promise.await (/home/cameron/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.17tso1e++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:35:12)
    at /tools/cordova/runner.js:98:17
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:271:13
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:264:29
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:262:18
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:253:23
    at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
    at Object.capture (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:252:19)
    at CordovaRunner.startRunTargets (/tools/cordova/runner.js:97:37)
    at AppRunner._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:763:21)
    at AppRunner._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:876:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:403:12
```

Comment: Have you got the Android SDK up and running? Have you created an AVD?

Comment: Yes, I use Android Studio frequently